# How to delete individual records in Laravel 4.2 using resourceful routing?

Tags: php, laravel-4, delete-row

I'm building a "cookbook" app in Laravel 4.2 with resourceful routing set up for recipes and categories. On the categories/{$id}/edit page (edit.blade.php), I have a model-bound form to edit the category, and underneath that, I have an additional form posting to the `CategoryController@destroy` method to delete, but every time I try, it throws a  `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` (which is a protected method). I have tried both "delete" and "destroy" on my destroy($id) function, but each throws the same error. Do I need to put something on the model or routes.php to allow deletions?

*Method being called:*

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->destroy();

    return Redirect::to('/categories');
}
```

*And form which is calling it:*

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('CategoryController@destroy', $category->id))) }}

{{ Form::submit('Delete Category', ['class' => 'red_button']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

*Category model* (which has no reference to deletions, but I'm adding it just in case):

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {
    /*Whitelist what user can enter into form and submit*/
    protected $fillable = [
'name', 'description', 'thumbnail'
    ];

    /*Set up One To Many relationship for users to recipes*/
    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this -> hasMany('Recipe');
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find your solution in the revision history and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

By default when you open a form whith Form::open the method used is "POST", you need to set this method to DELETE instead.

Since you use resourceful routing the destroy action is attached to the HTTP DELETE method. To clarify this, execute this command:

```
php artisan routes
```

This command show you a detailed list of your routes asociations and HTTP methods.

To solve the problem try this:

```
 {{ Form::open(array(
     'action' => array('CategoryController@destroy', $category->id),
     'method' => 'delete')) }}
```

I Hope works for you.

Comment: Thanks, OmeCoatl--I usually run php artisan routes once a day when I get started just to refresh my memory! I get so confused between the "delete" and "destroy." I tried adding your method call to the form, and now it is throwing an error on that CategoryController@destroy method instead (the first method in my original post destroy($id):

Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::destroy(), called in C:\Users\Paula\alchemy\app\controllers\CategoryController.php on line 141 and defined

Comment: Oh woo hoo! I added "$id" inside the "destroy" part, even though all the examples I had showed that blank, and now it works. I changed my Controller method to:

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->destroy($id);

        return Redirect::to('/categories');
    }

Comment: I glad you figured out!, I think [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) can clarify a bit the inital problem you have with the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Dont forget to mark the answer if you think is for any help, or simply mark +1, if you think is a little help

Comment: Thanks, OmeCoatl--I DID try to vote yours up, because it certainly was helpful! I do not have the reputation to vote yet ;( When I do I will come back and vote it up--not sure how long that will take...